# Cannot call Process.EnterDebugMode() without causing the Exception

Tags: c#, .net, bsod

I try to BSOD myself(force blue screen of death) whenever I shutdown my application. Unfortunately when I call `Process.EnterDebugMode();` I get an exception: `Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller`.

I write keylogger(that part is done) which suppose to spy on the serviceman who will repair my laptop so I will know if he didn't make any funny business.

```
[DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int NtSetInformationProcess(IntPtr hProcess, int processInformationClass, ref int processInformation, int processInformationLength);

public static void Main() {
    int isCritical = 1;  // we want this to be a Critical Process
    int BreakOnTermination = 0x1D;  // value for BreakOnTermination (flag)


    Process.EnterDebugMode();  //acquire Debug Privileges

    // setting the BreakOnTermination = 1 for the current process
    NtSetInformationProcess(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, BreakOnTermination, ref isCritical, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: what happens when the serviceman uses a livecd of some obscure os (linux, haiku, bsd)? Not much use for the keylogger then :) though it sounds like a fun exercise

Comment: @Icepickle Thanks for the tought. Any other way than to block his access to the laptop? He just needs to replace keyboard(warranty is still valid, I could do it myself but this way it's free).

Comment: Anyone who has physical access to your computer can get in to it, somehow. Granted, it would be very unprofessional for someone performing warranty service to access your private information...

Comment: @Yoda pull the hard drive :)

Comment: @Icepickle My retailer told me that Dell's service doesn't like when people do that(warranty issues). We found out that our laptop has a kind of warranty where technician comes to your house the next day and repairs at your home. 10 minutes of work, no questions asked(one actually, does all or some keys don't work?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program will need to be running with administrator privileges. Your program will behave as you expect if you do so.

You can use an app.manifest to easily have your program request privileges with an app.manfest - right click on your project in VS and add an Application manifest file. There's instructions in the generated comments, but you'll need to replace

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

with

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: My ears still buzzing ; ).